# Always getting 1 as number of members discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am adding a serverinfo command to my bot but when I test it, it always says there are one member when there clearly is more than that.
Here's my code:`

```
@client.command()
async def serverinfo(ctx):
    author = ctx.author.name
    guild = ctx.guild
    num=len(ctx.guild.members)
    
    infos = {
        'name': ctx.guild.name,
        'created_at': ctx.guild.created_at,
        'num_of_people': num
    }
    hexs = hexes[random.randint(0, len(hexes)-1)]
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Server Info", color = hexs)
    embed.add_field(name = "Server name: ", value = infos['name'], inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name="Server created at", value =infos["created_at"], inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Number of server members", value=infos["num_of_people"], inline=False)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed =embed)`
```

I could not find anything related to this.
There is no errors.

Comment: len(Guild.members) will always return 1, dont use len with anything to do with discord

Comment: how do i fix it then?

Comment: look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are better ways to do this but:

```
print(ctx.guild.member_count)
```

I think discord.py has an inbuilt way of doing this but I've forgotten so oh well